# Group only certain rows with GROUP BY

Tags: mysql, group-by, greatest-n-per-group

#### Schema

I have the following set-up in MySQL database:

```
CREATE TABLE items (
  id SERIAL,
  name VARCHAR(100),
  group_id INT,
  price DECIMAL(10,2),
  KEY items_group_id_idx (group_id),
  PRIMARY KEY (id)
);

INSERT INTO items VALUES 
(1, 'Item A', NULL, 10),
(2, 'Item B', NULL, 20),
(3, 'Item C', NULL, 30),
(4, 'Item D', 1,    40),
(5, 'Item E', 2,    50),
(6, 'Item F', 2,    60),
(7, 'Item G', 2,    70);
```

#### Problem

I need to select:

- **All** items with `group_id` that has `NULL` value, **and**
- **One** item from each group identified by `group_id` having the **lowest** price.

#### Expected results

```
+----+--------+----------+-------+
| id | name   | group_id | price |
+----+--------+----------+-------+
|  1 | Item A |     NULL | 10.00 | 
|  2 | Item B |     NULL | 20.00 | 
|  3 | Item C |     NULL | 30.00 | 
|  4 | Item D |        1 | 40.00 | 
|  5 | Item E |        2 | 50.00 | 
+----+--------+----------+-------+
```

#### Possible solution 1

Two queries with `UNION ALL`:

```
SELECT id, name, group_id, price FROM items
WHERE group_id IS NULL
UNION ALL
SELECT id, name, MIN(price) FROM items
WHERE group_id IS NOT NULL
GROUP BY group_id;
```

```
/* EXPLAIN */
+----+--------------+------------+------+--------------------+--------------------+---------+-------+------+----------------------------------------------+
| id | select_type  | table      | type | possible_keys      | key                | key_len | ref   | rows | Extra                                        |
+----+--------------+------------+------+--------------------+--------------------+---------+-------+------+----------------------------------------------+
|  1 | PRIMARY      | items      | ref  | items_group_id_idx | items_group_id_idx | 5       | const |    3 | Using where                                  | 
|  2 | UNION        | items      | ALL  | items_group_id_idx | NULL               | NULL    | NULL  |    7 | Using where; Using temporary; Using filesort | 
| NULL | UNION RESULT | <union1,2> | ALL  | NULL               | NULL               | NULL    | NULL  | NULL |                                              | 
+----+--------------+------------+------+--------------------+--------------------+---------+-------+------+----------------------------------------------+
```

However it is undesirable to have two queries since there will be more complex condition in `WHERE` clause and I would need to sort the final results.

#### Possible solution 2

`GROUP BY` on expression ([reference](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18883400/3549014))

```
SELECT id, name, group_id, MIN(price) FROM items
GROUP BY CASE WHEN group_id IS NOT NULL THEN group_id ELSE RAND() END;
```

```
/* EXPLAIN */
+----+-------------+-------+------+---------------+------+---------+------+------+---------------------------------+
| id | select_type | table | type | possible_keys | key  | key_len | ref  | rows | Extra                           |
+----+-------------+-------+------+---------------+------+---------+------+------+---------------------------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | items | ALL  | NULL          | NULL | NULL    | NULL |    7 | Using temporary; Using filesort | 
+----+-------------+-------+------+---------------+------+---------+------+------+---------------------------------+
```

Solution 2 seems to be faster and simple to use but I'm wondering whether there is a better approach in terms of performance.

**Update:** According to [MySQL documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-handling.html), this query is illegal in SQL92 and earlier and may work in MySQL only.

Comment: See [groupwise max](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/groupwise_max).  (Or MIN, in your case.)

Comment: What should happen on ties (two rows with same `group_id` and same lowest `price`)?

Comment: @ypercubeᵀᴹ, good question. Both solutions return only one item (that was inserted first?) with minimal price which is fine for me.

Comment: By the way, the queries are invalid not only in SQL-92. They are invalid in any ANSI SQL version. It would be valid in recent versions, only if `group_id` was the `PRIMARY KEY` or a `UNIQUE NOT NULL` column. But then you wouldn't need the `group by` ;)

Answer (score 4):

First, **do not use** either of your two queries. Both have a group by some column (`GROUP BY group_id`) and then select other columns, non-aggregated (`SELECT id, name`). This may give you **wrong and unexpected results**, despite that it may work in your tests, with some small sized table.

Second, the `UNION ALL` is not a problem. If the two subqueries perform efficiently, then the final union is ok, too. If you need a sort, the efficiency will depend on how that sort differs from the indexes used.

Now, the problem of ["groupwise-max" or "greatest-n-per-group"](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/greatest-n-per-group) has many solutions (and even a tag, both at SO and here). There are two sub-problems, depending on whether ties can happen and what the wanted results are in those cases.

If you want all the tied rows, the solution with `GROUP BY` inside a derived table is usually good. In your case, that you want just one row returned per group, another approach is easier to write and usually performs very well when there is a small number of group overall:

```
SELECT id, name, price 
FROM items
WHERE group_id IS NULL

UNION ALL

SELECT i.id, i.name, i.price 
FROM 
    ( SELECT DISTINCT group_id 
      FROM items
      WHERE group_id IS NOT NULL
    ) AS di
  JOIN 
    items AS i
  ON  i.id = 
    ( SELECT id
      FROM items 
      WHERE group_id = di.group_id
      ORDER BY price, id             -- order for resolving ties
      LIMIT 1
    ) 
ORDER BY
    <some_columns> ;                 -- final order
```

An index on `(group_id, price, id)` will be helpful

Comment: Thank you very much for your thorough answer and solution, it works. But the output from `EXPLAIN` shows that [this solution](http://dba.stackexchange.com/a/132287/89637) is superior in terms of performance.

Comment: Have you made actual tests in a reasonable sized table? I don't object that some other solution may be more efficient but the Explain alone is not proof.

Answer (score 2):

According to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28090544/3549014) by [@axiac](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4265352/axiac), better solution in terms of compatibility and performance is shown below.

It is also explained in [SQL Antipatterns book, Chapter 15: Ambiguous Groups](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1934356557).

To improve performance, combined index is also added for `(group_id, price, id)` as suggested by [@ypercube](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/132279/89637).

#### Solution

```
SELECT a.id, a.name, a.group_id, a.price
FROM items a
LEFT JOIN items b 
ON a.group_id = b.group_id 
AND (a.price > b.price OR (a.price = b.price and a.id > b.id))
WHERE b.price is NULL;
```

See [explanation on how it works](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28090544/3549014) for more details.

By accident as a side-effect this query works in my case where I needed to include **ALL** records with `group_id` equals to `NULL` **AND** **one** item from each group with the lowest price.

#### Result

```
+----+--------+----------+-------+
| id | name   | group_id | price |
+----+--------+----------+-------+
|  1 | Item A |     NULL | 10.00 | 
|  2 | Item B |     NULL | 20.00 | 
|  3 | Item C |     NULL | 30.00 | 
|  4 | Item D |        1 | 40.00 | 
|  5 | Item E |        2 | 50.00 | 
+----+--------+----------+-------+
```

#### Explain

```
+----+-------------+-------+------+-------------------------------+--------------------+---------+----------------------------+------+--------------------------+
| id | select_type | table | type | possible_keys                 | key                | key_len | ref                        | rows | Extra                    |
+----+-------------+-------+------+-------------------------------+--------------------+---------+----------------------------+------+--------------------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | a     | ALL  | NULL                          | NULL               | NULL    | NULL                       |    7 |                          | 
|  1 | SIMPLE      | b     | ref  | PRIMARY,id,items_group_id_idx | items_group_id_idx | 5       | agi_development.a.group_id |    1 | Using where; Using index | 
+----+-------------+-------+------+-------------------------------+--------------------+---------+----------------------------+------+--------------------------+
```